# Javascript: multiple conditions in a single 'if' statement, comparing multiple sets of values

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am building an app for a booking process. I have a bunch of selectable options, whose values are saved and the user is moved onto the next step in the process. The options are numbered 0-6. 0-4 can be thought of as one 'group', while options 5 & 6 are a separate 'group'. Now, what I need to happen is if the user changes their mind and goes back and selects a new option belonging to a different group, then it will trigger some functionality. See illustration below:

```
0 }
1 }
2 } --- 0 -4 is the first 'group'
3 }
4 }

5 } --- 5 & 6 can be thought as a different 'group'
6 }
```

I am trying to replicate this logic with an `if` statement. I have the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
                if((((c_sav === 4 || c_sav === 5) && (val_c !== 4 && val_c !== 5)) 
                   || ((c_sav !== 4 && c_sav !== 5) && (val_c === 4 || val_c === 5)))){
                    // Some logic...
                }
```

The variable names are just `c_sav` = Saved option from the first time the user makes a selection. `val_c` = The newly selected option.

Could anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

**EDIT** OK, perhaps I'm not being clear enough. If a user selects any option from the first group (0-4), then goes back and selects any option from the *same group*, 0-4, then *I don't care*. But if in this case they select either 5 or 6 (which are in the second group), then I want to evaluate to true (ie. trigger the function). *Conversely* If they select either 5 or 6 the first time round, then go back and select either 5 or 6, again, *I don't care*, but if in this case, they selected either 0,1,2,3 or 4, then I want to trigger the function.

I don't know how to explain it any more clearly...!

Comment: What's wrong with `if (c_sav !== val_c)`?

Comment: what is the use of (c_sav === 4 || c_sav === 5)  and (c_sav !== 4 && c_sav !== 5) together.better do not check this values.

Comment: Hi Matt - Suppose a user had selected 4. Then goes back and selects 5. These are both in the same 'group', therefore, in that instance I WOULDN'T want to trigger the function. Or, if they had selected any option from the first group (0-4), then went back and selected a different option from the *same group* (0-4) then, again, that doesn't need to trigger anything. It's only when an option from a different group is selected. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Inigo as per your explanation above they are in different group.

Comment: Just looking at the code, I'm going to suggest this generally - there's probably a better way to do this. Perhaps store which group each option is associated with somewhere, and then just check the "group" directly?

Comment: If something you're trying to do seems unreasonably complicated, it often is.

Comment: Good advice, sphanley. I guess it's my own shortsightedness to blame... This is something I am trying to graft on at the last minute..

Comment: I Agree with @MattBurland, why wouldn't his option work?

Comment: @psoshmo - No, Matt's option doesn't cover what I'm trying to do. See my first comment above. Can you follow what I'm trying to say?

Comment: @Inigo: `These are both in the same 'group'`, not according to what you put in your question they aren't. Please clarify your question if you want people to be able to answer. And I agree with sphanley's comments. You probably should rethink how you've organized you code.

Comment: If you are going with different "groups", then something like `if((c_sav <= 4 && val_c > 4) || (c_sav > 4 && val_c <= 4))`

Comment: @MattBurland, I am taking note of what you're saying, and will see if I can organise my code in a better way. In the meantime... please see my latest edit.

Comment: Ah, that looks much neater... yes, I think you've got it. Let me try...

Comment: I just realised the mistake in my first comment- I meant to say `Suppose a user had selected 5. Then goes back and selects 6` Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you might handle this. Given that `0..4` is one group and `5,6` is another group, the simplest solution is something like:

```
if((c_sav <= 4 && val_c > 4) || (c_sav > 4 && val_c <= 4)) {
    // Do something
}
```

This might be all you need, but it's not very robust or easy to maintain if your group boundaries change (or options are resorted somehow). A better alternative might be something like this:

```
var groups = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2];
```

So you could then do:

```
if (groups[c_sav] !== groups[val_c]) {
   // Do something
}
```

Or you could use an object, which gives you some more flexibility:

```
var groups = { 0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2 };
```

And can be used the same way. The object, however, makes it easier if your options are numeric (you could use string keys instead) or aren't continuous.

The best option would be if whatever you have in `c_sav` and `val_c` was an object that had a `group` property. Then you'd just compare them:

```
if (c_sav.group !== val_c.group) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Ah, the array method is awesome! Definitely the way to go, thank you!